# How to kill any session on basis of just SessionID

Tags: java, session, session-variables, session-state, httpsession

*Given that,*

I have a

> USER_ACTIVITY_LOG table

that contains

> USER_ID,  SESSION_ID,  ACTIVITY_CODE(Login/LogOut/TimeOut) &
>   ACTIVITY_TIME columns

in that. It updates all activities performed on the application in the table on basis of UserId & SessionId.

*Problem Statement :*
I want to restrict logins to maximum 2 users with the same credentials on my application.

Say at a time 2 users are logged into the application with the same credentials (eg: admin/admin) and now 3rd user is trying to log into application with the same credentials. In such case the oldest logged in user session should be invalidated.

I have to query **USER_ACTIVITY_LOG** table on every user login and check number of users logged in with the same userId and are not logged out.
If I get count of 2 users that are still logged in, I simply want to *invalidate the session* of the oldest user on basis of just **SESSION_ID**.

Is that possible ?

My project is on Java 8, Jboss 6.4, J2EE, Struts 2 & Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fix I found out and I am using it as of now. No matter it will impact the performance a bit.

```
public void expireSessionWithId(String sessionID)
{  
     try { 
        MBeanServer server = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

        ObjectName objectName=new ObjectName("jboss.web:type=Manager,path=/test,host=default-host");

        // declare signature of the parameter
        String[] sig = { "java.lang.String"};
        // declare parameter
        Object[] opArgs1 = { sessionID };
        // call the method
        String value = (String) server.invoke(objectName, "expireSession",
                opArgs1, sig);

        System.out.println(value);
    } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
        //handle the exception
    } catch (InstanceNotFoundException e) {
        //handle the exception
    } catch (ReflectionException e) {
        //handle the exception
    } catch (MBeanException e) {
        //handle the exception
    }

}
```